# Namespace for prefix 'xsi' has not been declared error on validating

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xsd-validation

I'm trying to validate an XML against a schema.
This is the header of the XML file, generated using the instructions provided by the government services for the transmission of VAT data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>

    <p:RichiestaCertificatoDispositivo>

xmlns:p="http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/corrispettivi/v1.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" versione="1.0"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/corrispettivi/v1.0/CorrispettiviMessaggiTypes_v1.0.xsd">
    </p:RichiestaCertificatoDispositivo>
```

Validating it against the following schema header I have the above error.
This is the schema header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
    xmlns="http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/corrispettivi/v1.0"
targetNamespace="http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/corrispettivi/v1.0"
version="1.0">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="./xmldsig-core-schema.xsd" />
```

Where's the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your "namespace declarations" are not within the start tag of an element, they are in a text node that appears between two start tags. They are therefore not recognized as namespace declarations.

```
<p:RichiestaCertificatoDispositivo>
                                ==^==
xmlns:p=
```

Comment: Well you can't expect people to find errors in your code if the code you post has different errors from the original.